# Python pandas: Operation on a column - Error: must be str not int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, error-handling

I'm just trying to add 1 to all values in the column 'day' in df:

```
df
  day
1  1
2  2
3  3
0  0
```

I need:

```
df
  day
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

I tried:

```
df['day']=df['day'].apply(lambda x: x + 1)
```

and

```
df['day']+=1
```

Both results in ERROR: TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: not `ERROR: TypeError: must be int, not str` ?

Comment: `df['day']=df['day'].astype(int) + 1` works?

Comment: Try this : df['day']=df['day'].astype(int).apply(lambda x: x + 1)

Comment: @jezrael  Damn, as fast as ever. : D

Comment: Looks like the dataframe contains `1`, etc. as *strings*, not integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems error is:

> ERROR: TypeError: must be int, not str

And solution:

```
df['day']=df['day'].astype(int) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, this work!
Weirdly, when I was doing:
    `type(df.iloc[1].day)`
It was telling me : `numpy.int64`

Comment: I think problem was mixed data - some data was int and some strings. For checking use `print (df['day'].apply(type))`

Comment: You are welcome! And I am curiuos, not typo in error? It is `TypeError: must be str, not int` ?